# Add data to a submitted form object inside a controller in Symfony2

Tags: php, forms, controller, symfony

I want to save some data where part of it is from the user where they submit it through a form and the other part is generated in the actual controller. So something like:

```
# controller
use Acme\SomeBundle\Entity\Variant;
use Acme\SomeBundle\Form\Type\VariantType;

public function saveAction()
{
    $request = $this->getRequest();

    // adding the data from user submitted from
    $form = $this->createForm(new VariantType());
    $form->bindRequest($request);


    // how do I add this data to the form object for validation etc
    $foo = "Some value from the controller";
    $bar = array(1,2,3,4);

    /* $form-> ...something... -> setFoo($foo); ?? */

    if ($form->isValid()) {

        $data = $form->getData();

        // my service layer that does the writing to the DB
        $myService = $this->get('acme_some.service.variant');
        $result = $myService->persist($data);
    }

}
```

How do I get `$foo` and `$bar` into the `$form` object so that I can validate it and persist it?

Answer (score 0):

Here's the general pattern I'm using:

```
public function createAction(Request $request)
{
    $entity = new Entity();
    $form = $this->createForm(new EntityType(), $entity);

    if ($request->getMethod() == 'POST') {
        $foo = "Some value from the controller";
        $bar = array(1, 2, 3, 4);

        $entity->setFoo($foo);
        $entity->setBar($bar);

        $form->bindRequest($request);
        if ($form->isValid()) {
            $this->get('some.service')->save($entity);
            // redirect
        }
    }

    // render the template with the form
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Reading the code for the `bind` method of the Form class, we can read this:

```
// Hook to change content of the data bound by the browser
$event = new FilterDataEvent($this, $clientData);
$this->dispatcher->dispatch(FormEvents::BIND_CLIENT_DATA, $event);
$clientData = $event->getData()
```

So I guess you could use this hook to add your two fields.